# Convert booleans to real true and false strings in PHP http_build_query

Tags: php, json, query-string

As stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php#122232) PHP's `http_build_query` function converts booleans to integers in the resulting string.

Is there a way that:

```
$a = ["teste1" => true, "teste2" => false];
echo http_build_query($a);
```

The result can be `teste1=true&teste2=false`

The main issue is because I have a JSON that should be converted as query string and the parameters sorted. My logic is:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
$query = http_build_query($decoded);
$exploded = explode('&', $query);
sort($exploded);
$params = implode('&', $exploded);
```

But the resulting string contains `0` and `1` instead of `false` and `true`. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a solution for my issue, I forgot to mention that the JSON is decoded to a multidimensional array, so:

```
function normalizeArray($array) {
  foreach ($array as &$el) {
      if (is_bool($el)) {
        $el = ($el) ? "true" : "false";
      } elseif (is_array($el)) {
        $el = normalizeArray($el);
      }
  }
  return $array;
}


$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
$normalized = normalizeArray($decoded);

$query = http_build_query($normalized);
$exploded = explode('&', $query);
sort($exploded);
$params = implode('&', $exploded);
```

I am still stuck to the explode/implode solution, that's because the `http_build_query` makes multidimensional keys correctly like: `level1[level2][level3]=something` and with previous solutions I lost the "parent" level key names.

Answer (score 2):

After you have decoded the JSON to array,

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');    
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);
```

You can use `ksort` to sort it by key. Then you'll only need to use `http_build_query` once rather than implode/explode, etc.

```
ksort($decoded);

$params = http_build_query(array_map('boolsToString', $decoded));

function boolsToString ($value) {
    if ($value === true) return 'true';    // strict comparison with === is necessary
    if ($value === false) return 'false';
    return $value;
}
```